# What kind of index should be added to mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
);
  
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`message` text NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

These are `mysql` tables and here is the query.

```
select COUNT(1)  
from  posts inner 
join users on posts.user_id = users.id  
where email = 'test@gmail.com' 
  and created_at > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

What kind of index would you add to the `posts` table to make this query work efficiently?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: An index on the foreign key user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have an index on `users.email` because of the UNIQUE KEY. This will optimize the row selection for your condition on email.

The primary key `users.id` is implicitly part of the index, and this will be used to look up the matching rows in `posts`.

Then you need an index on `posts` so each respective `users.id` can locate the matching rows efficiently. The index should also have a second column on `created_at` for the range condition.

```
ALTER TABLE posts ADD INDEX (user_id, created_at);
```

You can see how this affects the EXPLAIN and see that indexes are used.

Before new index:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | NULL       | const | PRIMARY,email | email | 1022    | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | posts | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL  | NULL    | NULL  |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
```

The join on `posts` will be forced to do a table-scan.

After new index:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | NULL       | const | PRIMARY,email | email   | 1022    | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | posts | NULL       | range | user_id       | user_id | 8       | NULL  |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+--------------------------+
```

The join to `posts` uses an index.

---

You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), or the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU) of me presenting it.